# dynamically created input button is being skipped by tabbing ... how to set tabindex

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tabindex

I have dynamically created a table with elements followed by a search and reset button. In general tabbing works through input fields and select fields in the table. Tabbing skips over checkbox which is not bothering me. However, after the table comes two buttons, search and reset. Adding these buttons dynamically will get skipped over when tabbing.

```
$('#' + div_id).append('<input type="button" class = "button" value="Search" onclick="'+this.table_name+'.submitSearch()">');
$('#' + div_id).append('<input type="button" class = "button" value="Reset" onclick="'+ this.table_name +'.resetSearch()">');
```

I have tried adding the following code:

```
$(":input:not(:hidden)").each(function (i) 
    {
        console.log(this.id);
        $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1); 
    });
```

Which is not helping. Php generated html code works as expected.
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ahh.... different browsers are doing completely different things... safari is skipping all buttons on tab. Chrome is going through everything in a seemingly ordered randomized order (buttons first, then links, then the dynamically created table inputs)

Comment: Without `tabindex`, they should go through them in the order they appear in the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/craigiannazzi/jsqbbp9w/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are on a Mac? Checkboxes and buttons are by default not included in the "tab" rotation. You can change the setting in Settings, Keyboard, Shortcuts, and choose All Controls at the bottom. The buttons and checkboxes should now be included in the rotation, and yes, it should cycle based on the order they appear in the DOM hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: Thank you , fixed, but OMG is nothing sacred anymore?

Comment: Apple decided you didn't need to tab to checkboxes or buttons. Just like they decided you don't need to sort folders separately from files in Finder.

Comment: Just want to re-state this is only affecting dynamically created elements, the php generated html works as expected